# Telegram API Code

Tags: c#, api, telegram

please Help us,

Telegram API code :

```
messages.dialogs#15ba6c40 dialogs:Vector<Dialog> messages:Vector<Message> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = messages.Dialogs;

messages.dialogsSlice#71e094f3 count:int dialogs:Vector<Dialog> messages:Vector<Message> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = messages.Dialogs;

---functions---

messages.getDialogs#eccf1df6 offset:int max_id:int limit:int = messages.Dialogs;
```

how i can make class for this ? - using TLSharp;
i have this class in Request folder ( from TLSharp );
how i can edit this class or create new class and work with Telegram API method ? ( telegram API is very Unclear for we )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using TLSharp.Core.MTProto;

namespace TLSharp.Core.Requests
{
    class GetHistoryRequest : MTProtoRequest
    {
        InputPeer _peer;
        int _offset;
        int _max_id;
        int _limit;

    public List<Message> messages;
    public List<Chat> chats;
    public List<User> users;

       public GetHistoryRequest(InputPeer peer, int offset, int max_id, int limit)
        {
           _peer = peer;
           _offset = offset;
           _max_id = max_id;
           _limit = limit;
        }

       public override void OnSend(BinaryWriter writer)
         {
           writer.Write(0x92a1df2f);
           _peer.Write(writer);
           writer.Write(_offset);
           writer.Write(_max_id);
           writer.Write(_limit);
         }

        public override void OnResponse(BinaryReader reader)
            {
                bool messagesSlice = reader.ReadUInt32() == 0xb446ae3; // else messages#8c718e87

           if (messagesSlice) reader.ReadInt32(); // count

           // messages
           var result = reader.ReadUInt32(); // vector#1cb5c415
           int messages_len = reader.ReadInt32();
           messages = new List<Message>(messages_len);
           for (var i = 0; i < messages_len; i++)
           {
               var msgEl = TL.Parse<Message>(reader);

               messages.Add(msgEl);
           }

           // chats
           reader.ReadUInt32();
           int chats_len = reader.ReadInt32();
           chats = new List<Chat>(chats_len);
           for (int i = 0; i < chats_len; i++)
               chats.Add(TL.Parse<Chat>(reader));

           /*
           // users
           reader.ReadUInt32();
           int users_len = reader.ReadInt32();
           users = new List<User>(users_len);
           for (int i = 0; i < users_len; i++)
               users.Add(TL.Parse<User>(reader));
           */
       }

    public override void OnException(Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Confirmed => true;
    public override bool Responded { get; }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify the problem a bit more?

Comment: if you know TLSharp , help me about how i can add more class like message.getDialog into TLSharp